# Projection of 4D sphere to 3D - focus point

Tags: stereographic-projections

I just finished watching [this interesting/funny Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhuaPhahHbU) on stereographic projection. In the video he demonstrated that one could draw an $n$-dimensional sphere onto an $(n-1)$-dimensional object (*plane?*).

In his examples he placed the light at the top of the shape, what he called the "north pole". For $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ the point was the top of the sphere. However, for obvious reasons, you can only see the output of the mapping $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. So it got me wondering, *how do we define the "north pole" of a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$, within the context of projection? In $\mathbb{R}^n$?*

For 2-dimensions we use the point with the max $y$ value. For 3-dimensions we use the point with the max $z$ value. For 4-dimensions is it the maximized point along the $w$-axis? If so, what does this look like and ***how do we know*** it's a pole for stereographic projection? I don't know much advanced topology, or any for that matter, so I'm looking for an answer with a $(3 \text{ or } 2)$-dimensional analogy or simplified explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: using the stereographic projection you can project an $n$-dimensional sphere onto (what is called) a **hyperplane**, the $(n-1)$-dimensional object of your question.

For your second question, let's start defining (in one of the many possible ways) the stereographic projection:

> Consider the unit sphere in the $3$-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $N = (0, 0, 1)$ be the *north pole* and $S=\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{N\}$ be the rest of the sphere. The plane $z = 0$ runs through the center of the sphere and the *equator* is the intersection of the sphere with this plane. For any point $p$ on $S$ there is a unique line through $N$ and $p$, and this line intersects the plane $z = 0$ in exactly one point $p^\prime$. We define the stereographic projection of $p$ to be this point $p^\prime$ in the plane.

As explained in the video of your question, the stereographic projection has nice properties like the **conformality**, meaning that it preserves the angles, despite it does not preserve area. In such a projection, circles on the sphere that do *not* pass through the point of projection are projected to circles on the plane and circles on the sphere that *do* pass through the point of projection are projected to straight lines on the plane.

I said this is one of the many ways we can define it, and you can check [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html) why and how to define others. Using this idea, I will try to answer your second question:

As you said in the $3$-dimensional space the notion of *north pole* is basically the point on the sphere with maximum $z$-coordinate for a given coordinate system and this can be extended to any dimension by just considering the point $(0,0,0\dots,0,1)$ as the distinguished *north pole*.

But you don't really need this point. In general, one can define a stereographic projection from any point $w\in\mathbb{S}^n$ on the $n$-sphere onto any hyperplane $\Pi\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that

- $\Pi$ is perpendicular to the diameter through $w$
- $\Pi$ does not contain $w$.

As long as $\Pi$ meets these conditions, then for any point $p$ other than $w$ (our distinguished point now) the line through $p$ and $w$ meets $\Pi$ in exactly one point $p^\prime$, which is defined to be the **stereographic projection** of $p$ onto $\Pi$. I use the terminology *stereographic* in the previous sentence because this projection has the same essential properties as the one in the $3$-dimensional case from the north pole $N$: they are smooth bijections with smooth inverse defined everywhere except at the projection point and they are conformal and not area-preserving.

Comment: How do we know for every point $p$ on $S$, there is a unique line thru $N$ and $p$ that intersects $z=0$? This seems rather intuitive for 2 and 3 dimensions, but I don't want to generalize based on intuition.

Comment: @Dando18 In the notation that I used in the answer, your question would be *how do we know for every point $p$ on $S$, there is a unique line thru $w$ and $p$ that intersects $\Pi$?* I'm doing this remark since you ask for the generalized case. Basically we are considering $\ell\cap\Pi$, where $\ell$ is the line mentioned before. This intersection can be $\ell$ (if it's contained in $\Pi$) or something with less dimension (a point). Since $\Pi$ is perpendicular to to the diameter through $w$, $\ell$ is not contained in $\Pi$ and $\ell\cap\Pi$ is a point.

Comment: @Dando18 Sorry, I am reading your question again and I think I misunderstood it: are you asking why the line joining two points is unique? That should need explanation and does not depend on the dimension of the space...

Comment: no I was asking how do we know there exists such a unique line ($\exists \ell$), which your first comment answered. Thanks!